# Pipeline runs when committed to feature branch

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am setting up pipelines in Azure for the first time.

I have an azure-pipelines.yaml file on dev which I created in Azure.
When I make a change on another branch (the yaml file is also on that branch) the pipeline runs for the branch but I have stated in the yaml the the trigger is dev.

[image: The pipeline]

```
    trigger:
      - dev

    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    steps:
      - task: MSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build API og WEB'
      inputs:
        solution: '**.*proj'
```

I only that the pipeline to run when changes are made on dev.
How can I achive that?

Comment: You could try the `exclude *`  https://medium.com/@geralexgr/build-triggers-on-azure-devops-pipelines-65729db8df50

Comment: should be 'trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev'

Answer (score 0):

@Paizo is right.

I changed to

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
```

and deleted the pull request that was pending if that matters.